# Cannot read property 'ref' of undefined in Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Try to run the function in Firebase Cloud Function once Cloud Function data generates. Actually, I want to run `sendEmail` triggered by adding the `events` collection's data. **But the events occur several times not once.**

So I have tried to add `publish` field and turn out to be `true` after the event occurs. But following error occurs.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'ref' of undefined

```
exports.sendEmail = functions.firestore
  .document("events/{eventId}")
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {
    if (!published) {
      const { published } = snap.data();
      // send an email
    }
    return snap.after.ref.set(
      {
        published: true,
      },
      { merge: true }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onCreate triggers receive a [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_firestore_#documentsnapshot) object as the first argument, which contains the contents of the document that was just created.  It doesn't have a property called `after`.  So you can't say `snap.after.ref`, because `snap.after` is undefined.  That's why you're getting the error message.

You might be confusing onCreate with onUpdate and onWrite, which both receive a Change object, which has `before` and `after` properties.

It's not entirely clear to me what exactly you're trying to accomplis here, but an onCreate trigger should not execute repeatedly, unless it's generating errors and retries are enabled.